# How to massive delete in php-activerecord where id NOT in list?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm running a CodeIgniter application with PHP-Activerecord installed and I need to do a massive delete.  The PHP-AR library supports massive update and delete, but the function only takes the ids that you want to delete/update.  I'm trying to do a massive delete where the ids are NOT in the list.

> delete from table where id not in (1,2,3...,500)

Unfortunately, the PHP-Activerecord website is of no help, and their forums are so horribly built (no search... seriously?) that I'm truly stuck.

**edit:** Please note, **CodeIgniter's built-in ORM is not the same as PHP-Activerecord.**  Just thought I'd clarify that.

Comment: `$this->db->query('delete from.....')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late but this may help someone else. In **PHPActiveRecord**, do it in this way:

```
$ids_to_delete = array(1,2,3);
YourModel::delete_all(array('conditions' => array('id NOT IN (?)', $ids_to_delete)));
```

Ref: http://www.phpactiverecord.org/docs/ActiveRecord/Model#methoddelete_all

Answer (score 2):

SInce active record is actually build string query with function, you can use this method:
- make your list as string
- make this query : $this->db->where('id not in',$string)->delete('table')